# How was non-decimal money represented in software?

Tags: decimal, currency

A lot of the answers to the questions about the accuracy of `float` and `double` recommend the use of `decimal` for monetary amounts.  This works because today all currencies are decimal except [MGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malagasy_ariary) and [MRO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauritanian_ouguiya), and those have subunits of 1/5 so are still decimal-friendly.

But what about the software used in U.S. stock markets when prices were in 1/16ths of dollar?  The accuracy of binary data types wouldn't have been an issue, right?

Going further back, how did pre-1971 British accounting software deal with pounds, shillings, and pence?  Did their versions of COBOL have a special `PIC` clause for it?  Were all amounts stored in pence?  How was decimalisation handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PL/I had a type specifically for British currency - I don't know about COBOL.  The British currency at one time incorporated farthings, or a quarter of a penny; I'm not sure though that computers had to deal with those, just with half pennies or ha'pennies.

Accurate accounting usually uses special types - representing decimals exactly.  The new IEEE 754 has support for floating-point decimals, and some chips (notably IBM pSeries) have such support in hardware.

Comment: From what I read, in the days of neon-tube storage elements, some computing equipment in Britain had some special storage units designed around the currency, with each such register having a twelve-state tube, a ten-state tube, a two-state tube, and a bunch more ten-state tubes.

Answer (score 2):

COBOL could do it, eg PICTURE 9(4)D88D6 DISPLAY-ST see http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/downloads/10924  page 117

Answer (score 1):

1/16 can be represented in four digits as .0625.  For fractions of that type you just add some additional decimal places.